# Updating a value of dictionary in list of dictionaries in a collection using PyMongo

Tags: python, mongodb, mongodb-query, pymongo

The collection structure that I have is as follows:

```
defaultdict(
    lambda: {
        '_id' : None,
        'stuff' : [defaultdict(lambda : 0)]
    })
```

I am trying to initialise a list of dictionaries that I'll keep on updating in a way that if a dictionary's key already exists then I'll increase its value by 1 otherwise I'll update the list of dictionary with the new `key, value` pair. e.g. is the value of `stuff` is [] and I have come across a value `val` then the value of `stuff` will be `[{'val' : 1}]` and further if I get a value `val2` then `stuff = [{'val' : 1}, {'val2' : 1}]` and again if I get `val`, `stuff` should be `[{'val' : 2}, {'val2' : 1}]`.

I tried this:

```
table.update({'_id' : data['_id']}, \
             {'$inc' : {"stuff.$."+keyvalue : 1}})
```

where, `data` is a JSON object having an `_id` and a list of dictionaries `stuff`. Running this I received an `OperationFailure: The positional operator did not find the match needed from the query`.

I cannot figure out what to do? I am a Mongo newbie.

Comment: What do you mean by *if the dictionary already exists then I'll update its value by 1* ? what is `keyvalue`? can you show use your document?

Comment: @Michael I have updated the question with a better explanation. I hope it gives a better idea of what I asking?

Comment: Thanks! I will run this and let you know.

Comment: just make sure that  `_id == data['_id']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting the [**documentation**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/)

> When used with update operations, e.g. `db.collection.update()` and `db.collection.findAndModify()`,
>
> - the positional $ operator acts as a placeholder for the first element that matches the query document, and
> - the array field must appear as part of the query document.

So the `stuff` array should appear in your query. Now since you are doing conditional update you need to check if your array already has any subdocument with your `keyvalue` using [**`$exists`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/exists/).

```
if not table.find_one({ "_id": data['_id'], "stuff": {"$elemMatch": {keyvalue: { "$exists" : True }}}}):
    table.update({ "_id": data['_id'] }, { "$push": { "stuff": { keyvalue: 1 }}})
else:
    table.update({ "_id": data['_id'], "stuff": { "$elemMatch": { keyvalue: { "$exists" : True}}}}, { "$inc": { "stuff.$." + keyvalue: 1}})
```

Comment: In the first part should I also add `{upsert : True}`?

Comment: why will want that? you do not need to